# openMP - need for atomic or reduction clauses

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiprocessing, openmp

I am using openMP to parallelize a few statements. I am using the *parallel for* construct. The parallelized for loop looks like:

```
double solverFunction::apply(double* parameters_ , Model* varModel_)  
{
     double functionEvaluation = 0;
     Command* command_ = 0;
     Model* model_ = 0;

     #pragma omp parallel for  shared (functionEvaluation) private (model_,command_)
     for (int i=rowStart;i<rowEnd+1;i++)
     {
         model_ = new Model(varModel_);
         model_->addVariable("i", i);
         model_->addVariable("j", 1);
         command_ = formulaCommand->duplicate(model_);
         functionEvaluation += command_->execute().toDouble();
     }
}
```

It is workly *on average.* Execution time is *dramatically* reduced, and result is *as expected*. However, from time to time, especially for big problems (big number of iterations over i, big number of data to copy in copy constructor call

```
 model_ = new Model(varModel_);
```

, others?), it crashed. Call stack ends in classes such as qAtomicBasic (it is a program written in C++/Qt), QHash, and I have an idea it crashes because of concurrent read/write access in memory.

HOWEVER, model_ and command_ are private, so that each thread deals with a copy of each. In the variable model_, I copy varModel_, so that the pointer passed in argument is not altered by the threads. Alike, command_ is a copy of the member variable formulaCommand (duplicate is roughtly a copy constructer).

The possible flaws in my code I identified are

- functionEvaluation may be modified by several threads simultaneously
- copy constructor in statement

  model_ = new Model(varModel_);

reads the members for varModel_ in memory to construct the new (model_) instance. Concurrent access to varModel_ data members could occur, althought this not about altering their value here, but only reading them (affecting them to other variables).

Also, I see two improvements only (which I cannot test until a few days, but I ask for advice anyway):

- add atomic clause, so that functionEvalution is not concurrently written in
- add operator reduction(+,functionEvaluation), so that concurrency regarding access to functionEvaluation is dealt with automatically

Do these solutions seem to accuratly solve the problem and which is more efficient in general? Where does the problem can lie with the code I wrote? What are solutions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first observation is that, as you’ve noticed yourself, modifying `functionEvaluation` concurrently is a bad idea. It *will* fail.

The read-only access of `varModel_`, on the other hand, is not a problem. Neither is the copy constructor call (but where is it? Your code doesn’t show it).

Unrelatedly, using the `private` clause in C++ is a bad idea. Just declare the thread-private variables *inside* the parallel block (in this case, the `for` loop).

I also don’t see why you are using pointers here. Their use doesn’t make immediate sense – use stack-allocated objects instead.

The following modified code should work (I’ve also taken the liberty of unifying the coding style … why the trailing underscores?):

```
double solverFunction::apply(double parameters, Model const& varModel)
{
     double result = 0;

     #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)
     for (int i = rowStart; i < rowEnd + 1; ++i)
     {
         Model model(varModel);
         mode.addVariable("i", i);
         mode.addVariable("j", i);
         Command command = formulaCommand->duplicate(model);
         result += command.execute().toDouble();
     }

     return result;
}
```

Note that, due to inherent floating point inaccuracies, this code may yield *different* results from the sequential code. This is unavoidable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Konrad, I don't see how to do without the pointers: call to copy constructor `Model()` takes an argument which is a pointer to a Model, and `duplicate()` alike accepts a pointer to a Command. Is it more memory consumming / time consumming to use pointers, even if I delete them inside the loop ?

Comment: @dlib The first question is: why do these functions take pointers as arguments? But if this cannot be changed then you can do exactly what you’ve written in your comment. Using heap allocation here has simply no benefit over stack allocation, makes things more complex (manual memory management) and adds a small performance overhead. Also, see my updated answer, I’d overlooked another big (!) bug in your code before.

Comment: this is no bug, it's copy paste misunderstanding (shame), I modified above. I don't see how to use stack allocation here. Model(&model_) is not appropriate since I want to copy varModel inside new instance model_ ; I cannot work without copy constructor, that is with new.

Comment: @dlib See update for a fixed code. Concerning the copy constructor: that’s simply a constructor which takes a (const) reference of the class type. This isn’t the case in your code since you are passing a pointer. A copy constructor also has got nothing to do with `new` (my code isn’t using `new` but it’s still calling the model’s copy constructor).

Comment: this looks very good. I test this soon ! For the concern on copy constructor, I feel that I use here (with stack allocation) the default copy constructor, but not the home made one with signature Model(* Model), is that right?

Comment: @dlib Yes. That’s quite intentional. You should implement the *real* copy constructor if the default compiler-created isn’t fit for your purposes.

Comment: You should use a reduction clause instead of summing up to a vector and the calling accumulate.

Comment: @lucas1024 I’m never comfortable with using OMP reductions. I know that’s a weakness of character but for me OpenMP is a very low level wrapper of parallelism and I implement everything on top of it. Perhaps that’s because I *had* to implement my own parallelism library on top of it recently. … But you’re of course right. Fixed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for update with reduction,I think it is better so too.

Comment: @KonradRudolph my program works good. But I do not find how to have command stack allocated since Command class is abstract (must be) here. What can I do to avoid create delete in each loop, which seems be the time consuming point? Thanks !

Comment: @dlib If it’s abstract, just use a (`const`) reference instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph like that? `Command & command_= *(formulaCommand->duplicate(&model_));functionEvaluation += command_.execute().toDouble();` compile bus does not wok proerly however.

Comment: @dlib This code won’t work, as you’ve noticed since the value that you assign to `command` is a temporary. The long and the short of this is that in this case you should probably just use a pointer for `command` but don’t forget to delete it after the computation. Better yet, use a `unique_ptr` if you’re using C++11, or an `auto_ptr` if not.

Comment: @KonradRudolph is delete to happen in each loop, or only once after loops is sufficient Thanks again.

Comment: @dlib Well you create an object in each loop. Consequently you need to delete it in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrently modifying `functionEvaluation` is definitely a problem in your code and the best way to deal with it is the `reduction` clause.

A further problem is that fact that you are allocating heap memory by calling `new` in parallel, which is never a good idea for many iterations since there is a system-wide lock on calls to `new`. Consider switching to stack allocations, since the stacks are private to each thread, while the heap is shared.

Comment: Thanks! I don't see how to do without the pointers: call to copy constructor Model() takes an argument which is a pointer to a Model, and duplicate() alike accepts a pointer to a Command.

Comment: @dlib: Can't you change them to accept directly values instead of pointers?

Comment: @dlib: Then you could try to pass in the address of `model_`: `&model_`

Comment: I don't think so: in loop, I am creating model_, and passing varModel as an argument. I must copy varModel_, and I must use Model copy constructor (with argument a pointer to a Model). I don't see a work around.